# Why is it that, when I try to search for data that is beyond the first data entry in my double linked list, the program crashes?

Tags: c++

For my assignment, I am supposed to create a double linked list and have search, insert and delete functions alongside it. While developing the search function, I ran into an error of where, if someone was to search using a key that could not be matched with anything in the linked list, the program would crash -printing the memory address of where the first data of the linked list was located. But, alongside that, I ran into another error where, if I was to search for any data that was beyond the first data entry, the program would crash- printing the memory address of the first entry.

These issues stem from the fact that my search function isn't properly iterating through the entire list, but can only read the first entry without issue. So if I was to try to access any data that is beyond the first entry the whole program would crash. I know that's ultimately the issue, but I'm stumped on what I did that caused it and how I should fix it.

header.h:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef Header_H
#define Header_H
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
struct Node {
    T record;
    Node<T> *next;
    Node<T> *prev;
    Node() {
        next = NULL;
        prev = NULL;
    }
};


template<class T> 
class datax {
    Node<T> *top;
    Node<T> *bot;
public:
    datax() {
        top = NULL;
        bot = NULL;
    }
    ~datax() {}
    //Searches the list that has a requested key word
    void find();
    //Inserts into the list a requested word
    void insert();
    //Searches the list for a requested key word and pops it out
    void Delete();
    void show();
private:
};

template<typename T>
void datax<T>::show() {
    Node<T> *temp = top;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        cout << temp->record << "";
        temp = temp->next;
    }

}
template<typename T>
void datax<T>::Delete() {
    T get;
    Node<T>*ser = top;
    cin >> get;
    while (ser != NULL && ser->record != get) {
        ser = ser->next;

    }
    if (ser != NULL && ser->record == get) {
        cout << "Removing data from " << ser << endl;
        ser->next->prev = ser->prev;
        delete ser;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Data not found" << endl;
    }
}

template<typename T> 
void datax<T>::insert() {
    T val;
    Node<T> *ptr = new Node<T>;
    cin >> val;
    ptr->record = val;
    ptr->next = NULL;
    if (bot != NULL) {
        bot->next = ptr;
        ptr->prev = bot;
    }
    if (top == NULL) {
        top = ptr;
    }
    bot = ptr;
}
template<typename T>
void datax<T>::find() {
    T get;
    Node<T>*ptr= top;
    cin >> get;
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        cout << "Data not found" << endl;
    }
    else {
        while (top != NULL && ptr->record != get) {
            top->next = ptr;
        }

        if (ptr != NULL && ptr->record == get) {
            cout << "Found: " << ptr << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Data not found" << endl;
        }
    }

}

#endif // !Header_H
```

main:

```
// LinkedList.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include<iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include"Header.h"
    using namespace std;
        int main()
        {
            int take;
            datax<int> m;
            while (true) {
                cout << "\n\n1. Insert\n\n2.Find\n\n3.Delete" << endl;
                cin >> take;
                switch (take) {
                case 1:
                    m.insert();
                    m.show();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    m.find();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    m.Delete();
                    m.show();
                    break;
                default:
                    cout << "Error" << endl;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @melpomene Thank you for linking this to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your search loop:

```
while (top != NULL && ptr->record != get) {
    top->next = ptr;
}
```

Now, your condition is that you'll keep looping until either `top` is `NULL` OR `ptr->record` is what you're looking for. But in your loop body does `top` change? Does `ptr` change?? No!

In other words, if you don't exit this loop the first time, **you never will**.

You probably meant for this to look like:

```
while (ptr != NULL && ptr->record != get) {
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
```

Or if you're feeling fancy and wanted a one liner (that IMO is still readable):

```
for(ptr = top; ptr && ptr->record != get; ptr = ptr->next) { }
```

Comment: Wow. First, thank you so much for pointing that out. I really should have paid more attention to that. I really do appreciate you, scohe.

Comment: @pkpulsefall happy to help!